# What is the alternative function for fluent wait in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

What is the alternative function for fluent wait in selenium java? For ex.:- We can achieve assert true using if else condition, the same way how we can achieve fluent wait?

Interviewer told me that he doesn't need a fluent wait syntax.

Comment: WebDriverWaits are sort of pre-configured fluent waits.  Usually you'd be working with WebDriverWaits.  Your question, as is, isn't very clear.  Can you copy/paste what the interviewer's question was?

Comment: Hey Cynol, If you have added code and asked for the solution , others can answer but you asked a general topic and multiple threads are already present for this. as @pcalkins suggested, in the realtime projects we gonna use customised waits as per project.

Answer (score -1):

Implicit Wait:

Implicit wait sets a maximum time for the WebDriver to wait for an element to be present in the DOM. It is applied globally and is set once for the entire session.
Explicit Wait with ExpectedConditions:

Use explicit waits in combination with ExpectedConditions for more fine-grained control over waiting conditions.
Thread.sleep:

While not recommended in all cases due to its static nature, you can use Thread.sleep() to pause the execution for a specified period.
Custom Wait Functions:

You can create your own custom wait functions using loops and conditions based on specific requirements.

Comment: I can see you got a downvote, possible reasons are your answer is not relevant to the problem, As you are the beginner, from next time please be specific to the question and sure shot solution. Instead of writing all functions, you can simply compare important waits ( ex: here fluent vs explicit ). No need of implicit , which can help the reporter & stack community and also your score.